# i can not see google repository option in SDK manager in android studio

Tags: android

I can't see Google repository option in android studio. I have already installed latest Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w83RJ.png)

Comment: Some orthography fixes.

Comment: after installing google repository, have you restart your studio??

Answer (score 0):

According [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html), android support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository.

> The support libraries are now available through Google's Maven
>   repository. We no longer support downloading the libraries through the
>   SDK Manager, and that functionality will be removed soon..

You have to add maven in repositories tag of your project level `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

But of late it's recommended to use *AndroidX* instead of *support* library

> We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You
>   should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there is a possibility that the repository is already installed, especially if you have the latest version of Android Studio. Therefore, check under Tools and see if you can directly access Firebase. It is towards the end of the menu that pops up after clicking on Tools. If present, clicking it will bring up the Assistant Window and you will be good to go.